# TensorFlow Lite Inference on a PC very slow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm experimenting with TensorFlow Lite on the PC:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import interpreter as interpreter_wrapper


model_path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'model', 'yolov3.tflite')

interpreter = interpreter_wrapper.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

if input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32:
    floating_model = True

orig = cv2.imread('data/dog-cycle-car.png')

height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]

image, image_data = preprocess_image(orig, (height, width))

start = time.time()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image_data)
interpreter.invoke()
end = time.time()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

# Takes around 30 seconds on a PC
print("Inference time: {:.2f}s".format((end - start)))
```

However inference takes around 30 seconds, which seems slightly abnormal. Am  I missing something?

Comment: If you wrap the inference stuff in a loop (starting from the `start = time.time()` line and ending at the end of the snippet) and run it, say, 5 times, is every invocation as slow, or is it the first one only?

Comment: Every invocation is slow (I made it loop 10 times and averaged the results). At first I thought it was the warm up, but then on average it takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For issues on performance, please file a tracking issue on Github since there may be a bug.

The other question is how much of a performance difference is there? One factor is that the optimizations in Tensorflow Lite don't target x86 (where as Tensorflow does more so) and we target architectures more associated with mobile/embedded (e.g. arm).

Comment: The other thing to consider is multithreading. The number of threads you use should  match in your other benchmarks. 30s sounds extremely slow though, so filing an issue would be appropriate